# Plotting a specific row and a subset of this row's columns

Tags: plotting

I have the following data. Now, I not only wish to plot a specific row of the data, but also a subset of the columns in the chosen row. I can work out the first part, but plotting a specific part of the columns I cannot.

```
data = {{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}, {3, 30, 300}}}
```

My attempt for row 2 is:

```
ListLinePlot[data[[1 ;; 1, 2]]]
```

Comment: try `ListLinePlot[data[[1,2, {2,3}]]]` to plot row 2 and columns 2 and 3.

Comment: What if I needed columns c through c+n?

Comment: use `ListLinePlot[data[[1,2,c;;c+n}]]]`

Comment: [Here's the manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) on how to extract rows and columns.

Comment: It was the curly brackets that got me. I tried {c;;c+n}. By the way, your comment still has a curly bracket. The solution, of course, works when that is removed.

Comment: user120911, you can either use a `List` (`{1,2,5}`) specifying the columns explicitly or `Span` (`from;;to` without curly braces) specifying _all_ columns form column `from` to column `to` (equivalent to using `{from, from +1, from +2, ..., to -1, to}`).